# Date comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I am trying to compare a date in JS with todays date. This is what my code looks like.
But when I try to compare the date for 01/07/2014 then this is not working. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
var chsRedirectDate = "04/01/2013" ; //new Date("1 Apr 2013");
var today = new Date();
var dd    = today.getDate();
var mm    = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy  = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd};
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm};

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;


if (ee_value.toUpperCase() == 'TEST123') && (today >= chsRedirectDate))
   var url = "test.php" ;
   var newtab = window.open("url", null, "top=190,left=450, dependent=yes, directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,scrollbars=no,width=500,height=250,resizable=yes");
   window.close();
   newtab.location = url;
   newtab.focus();

   return false;

}

if (ee_value.toUpperCase() == 'TEST123') && (today < chsRedirectDate))
{
   alert('Testing');
}
```

Comment: Don't compare them as strings, use the Date object or the UNIX timestamps

Comment: If you *do* compare them as strings, you need to represent them as "yyyy/mm/dd" - the year has to be more significant than the month, and the month more than the day.

Comment: @mattedgod -- How to do that? new to Javascript

Comment: @Ditty http://www.electrictoolbox.com/unix-timestamp-javascript/

Comment: @suresh.g EE value is a string value. that is working fine. It is just the date.

Comment: If somebody can fix my code and update it then it would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = new Date();
var otherDay = new Date("04/01/2013");

alert(today >= otherDay);
```